# I'm giving up vs. I give up

Tags: progressive-aspect

Are both of the following sentences grammatically correct and, if so, is there any siginificant difference between simple and progressive aspect here?

> I give up (on sth. / sb.)
>
> I'm giving up (on sth. / sb.)

Comment: Aside from the fact that you'r question lacks the context, I think there is a difference because otherwise there wouldn't be different aspects!

Answer (score 7):

Both of your examples are correct and would be understood as meaning the same thing.
A slight nuance might be

> I give up

has more of a finality to it, you are already done with dealing with *something*, whereas

> I'm giving up

may mean you are about to *give up* but have not quite yet.

Comment: what about "Sooner or later **I will give up** smoking". Is it correct too?

Answer (score 0):

The more common of them is "**to give up**" since it is mostly a quick non-continuous action. However, "**to be giving up**" can often be used especially to mean that the action is taking too long to complete.

Much depends on the context you are using the verb in.

- Okay, I give up! How did you do this?
- I'm never giving up easily when I'm one against many in Counter-strike.

As for "**to give up on**" versus "**to be giving up on**" the latter conveys a certain degree of intention whereas the former states a completed action.

- I give up on you. = I have decided.
- I'm giving up on you. = I have the intention to. I have almost decided to.

Purely my thought is that mostly the latter can be undone. There is a certain percent of "**unless**" coming in action whereupon "**to be giving up on**" changes to the opposite. With "**to give up on**", this percent is barely there.